# Java : when a class need to be loaded in a JVM twice and more?

Tags: jvm

When I read something about JVM, it tells me that the namespace of JVM can identify a class loaded in the JVM, only the full name of the class is not useful! When or on which circumstance a class will be loaded in the jvm(I mean the same jvm) twice and more? Is this way a useful way?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply try to load the same class multiple times with reflection, then subsequent times will just return the already loaded class. This is a common situation, and there is nothing special about it.

It is possible to load the same class with different class loaders. In general, this is not necessary, and it can be very confusing. Because two instances of the same class loaded by different class loaders are not equal,

Comment: yes, i know that developers do not use two different class loaders to load the same class generally. But the jvm provides this feature, i just want to know more why to provide that? Is it a great feature that can do something amazing under certain circumstance ?

Comment: If you are running multiple applications inside the same JVM that require separation.  For example, multiple web applications inside the same Web container should not be able to interfere with each other. This also makes it possible to unload or upgrade one of those applications without affecting the other. Although that is very difficult to get right.

Comment: Bill is right. Read the article [HOW TO: Bootstrap Java programs in isolated classloaders](http://blog.markturansky.com/archives/21) as a little intro if you like. Another example would be two different versions of the same library in the main app and a container or two different containers etc.